# Django's transaction with a specified number of retries

Tags: django, transactions

I used to build systems using Google App Engine, in which I may resolve a racing condition with a decorator. I can also specify how many times I would like to retry the operation if collisions occur. The following is an example of ticket selling :

```
@ndb.transactional(retries=10)
def addNumSales(ticket):
    ticket.numSales += 1
    ticket.put()
```

Now I have to switch to Django and the transaction is handled as follows:

```
@transaction.atomic
def addNumSales(ticket):
    ticket.numSales += 1
    ticket.save()
```

The above just ensures an atomic transaction but there is no exception handling. I looked through Django's documentation, but couldn't find how to handle exceptions, especially specifying a number of retries. Any suggestions?

Comment: Atomicity in traditional databases works quite differently from GAE. First of all, transactions are blocking, and a conflicting transaction will simply delay the second transaction, not cause a failure, so retries make little sense (time-outs can theoretically occur, but are not an issue in practice on anything but sqlite). Also, the default isolation level is different. It might be a good idea to read up on the topic. Mark's answer solves any issues in this scenario.

Comment: This is THE answer that I am looking for. Thanks a lot, knbk.

Comment: I meant to say transactions work differently, not atomicity. But well, you get the point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your question about number of retries, you can write an atomic increment based off of the database value so there will be no collisions by using an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions):

```
def addNumSales(ticket):
    ticket.numSales = F('numSales') + 1
    ticket.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. What happen if another user is trying to add the number at the very same time? Would the process fail quietly? Or the process will be executed (again and again) until it succeeds? My case belongs to the latter.

Comment: By using the F expression, the database is simply told to increment the value in that row. There is no race condition or locking introduced, so there is no chance of collision.